# Swing components are not visible in custom layout manager

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I've made the following layout manager class:

```
public class MainFrameLayout extends BorderLayout
{
    private final JPanel north, center, south;

    /**
     * Constructor for this layout.
     */
    public MainFrameLayout()
    {
        super();

        north = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));
        center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new BoxLayout(center, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        south = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));

        north.setVisible(true);
        center.setVisible(true);
        south.setVisible(true);

        super.addLayoutComponent(north, NORTH);
        super.addLayoutComponent(center, CENTER);
        super.addLayoutComponent(south, SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints)
    {
        if (!(constraints instanceof MainFrameLayoutConstraints))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid constraints");

        switch ((MainFrameLayoutConstraints) constraints)
        {
            case NORTH:
                north.add(comp);
                break;

            case CENTER:
                center.add(comp);
                break;

            case SOUTH:
                south.add(comp);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

`MainFrameLayoutConstraints` is a generic `enum` class with only `NORTH`, `CENTER`, and `SOUTH` variants.

I attempted to use this layout in the following application:

```
public class MyApplication extends JFrame
{
    private final JFormattedTextField caseNumberBox;

    public MyApplication()
    {
        super("A Title Thingy");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        NumberFormat caseNumberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
        caseNumberBox = new JFormattedTextField(caseNumberFormat);
        caseNumberBox.setColumns(20);

        this.setLayout(new MainFrameLayout());
        this.add(new JLabel("Major Release Case: "), MainFrameLayoutConstraints.NORTH);
        this.add(caseNumberBox, MainFrameLayoutConstraints.NORTH);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
    }
}
```

Why, when I run this application, are my components (the label and text field) invisible even though the call to `pack()` sized the window appropriately to fit those fields?

Comment: Why would you create a layout manager like this? Just don't use the EAST, WEST contraints. Did you add debug code to the switch statement to see if the code is executing?

Comment: The code must be executing for the main frame to be sized appropriately. If I remove the calls to `add()` in the `MyApplication` constructor, the frame is not sized appropriately anymore. The components are being added but not kept. I did some debug code to set background colors for the panels, and none of the colors appeared. This leads me to believe that the panels are being removed before the frame becomes visible.

Comment: There is no need to create a custom layout manager. Just add the components to the frame using the default implementation of the BorderLayout.

Comment: This is more of an education thing at this point. I'd just like to know why they're gone. I've already implemented my desired interface using custom panels instead, but I still would like to understand why this code is behaving incorrectly.

Comment: A LayoutManager does not create components or add components to a panel. The LayoutManager only associates constraints with a component so the constraint can be used when the LayoutManager determines the size/location of components that have been added to the panel using the layout manager. You can't just create your own "MainFrameLayoutConstraints" because all the layout manger code is expecting a String constraint. If you want to limit the constraints then all you can do is change the edit to make sure the String is "North", "South" or "Center".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour is trying to create components inside the layout manager. While `MainFrameLayout` calls `super.addLayoutComponent()` for the components it creates, these are **not** added to the parent component itself. Therefore, the components you add to the frame count for the frame's preferred size calculation, as that's delegated to `BorderLayout` which assumes the content pane contains panels you created in the `MainFrameLayout` constructor, but they never get drawn as the panels haven't actually been added to the content pane.

A custom layout manager is the wrong tool for what you're trying to achieve. Simply use a nested layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's what the commentators said.. your custom layout isn't really necessary. You can add you components directly in your `MyApplication` class.

```
public MyApplication() {
    ...
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 1));
    ...            
    add(new JLabel("Major Release Case: "), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(caseNumberBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);            
    ...
}
```